# vue.js v-for How can I use object value?

Tags: vue.js

data structure

```
data(){
 return{
  countries:[
   {Germany:'de'},
   {Japan:'jp'},
   {China:'ch'}]
 }
}
```

and from those data  I only need value of the objects ex: 'de','jp','ch'

```
  <v-checkbox v-for="n in this.countries" :key="n" :label="`${n}`" :value="n"></v-checkbox>
```

but when I do this it only shows [object Object].
How can I put out only value from the object?

Comment: Why are you using `v-for` as it is a single checkbox here? It will anyways will have a single label & value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to output an entire object. That's why you're getting that output.

You need to access the object values. Try using `Object.values(n)[0]`. Something like this

```
<v-checkbox v-for="(n, index) in this.countries" :key="index" :label="Object.values(n)[0]" :value="n"></v-checkbox>
```

But it is better if you restructure your data object. Something similar to this

```
data(){
 return{
  countries:[{name: 'Germany', code: 'de'},
             {name: 'Japan', code: 'jp'},
             {name: 'China': code: 'ch'}
  ]
 }
}
```

And update your `v-for`

```
<v-checkbox v-for="n in this.countries" :key="n.code" :label="n.code" :value="n"></v-checkbox>
```

Also, there's no need for template strings here, you can use plain JS.
Your `key` is also wrong, as this is not unique. You can use `index` as in my first example, or use the `code` if that's unique.

Comment: thanks a lot! it works! and I can not change the data cuz it's comes from api... but thanks!

Comment: of course you can change the data:) Object.entries(this.countries).map( item => ({name: item[0], code: item[1]}) )